# How to re-position rows with SQL reporting services in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I am pretty much a noob when it comes to working with reports, so this may have a simple answer.

When I try to insert a new group into a table it always inserts it towards the top, and I can't figure out how to insert it below the bottom row. I've tried everything, including editing the raw XML. Here is an image of what I currently have:

[image: [picture of table](http://imgur.com/sAAfn)]

The desired outcome I am looking for is for the row with the '2' next to it to be below the label row with 'Order Type' and 'Quantity' columns. Any ideas on how I should do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The last row was actually marked as a footer, so everything was just being inserted above.